# saving embeded form values based on user session data

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form that has many embedded forms, which are select lists.

What I'm ideally looking to do, is to save the select list values.

I can get the form values by using:

```
$this->form->getValues()
```

var_dumping the above gives me something like:

```
    array
      'fields' => 
        array
          'Field' => 
            array
              'field' => string 'field' (length=7)
              'column' => int 0
              'id' => null
          'Field 1' => 
            array
              'field' => string 'field_1' (length=7)
              'column' => int 1
              'id' => null
          'Field 2' => 
            array
              'field' => string 'field_2' (length=19)
              'column' => int 10
              'id' => null
      'id' => string '51' (length=2)
```

I've then set the form values in the user session:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('something', $this->form->getValues());
```

I'm jsut wondering how I'd then set the select lists based on these saved values?

Thanks

EDIT:

In my `actions.class.php` i added the following after the `$this->form-save()`

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('user_fields', $this->form->getValues());
```

Then within my `configure()` method in my form class, imply used:

```
    if ($savedValues = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('user_fields'))
    {
        $this->setDefaults($savedValues);
    }
```

And it worked perfectly!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action after the form is created (and before `bind()` is called) you can do this:

```
$this->form = new YourForm();

if ($savedValues = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('something'))
{
  $this->form->setDefaults($savedValues);
}

// ...
```

Comment: I used your code and it worked great!! Thank you for your help.